# OutlookVBA for finding and replacing the text from original email

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run outlook VBA to find and replace text from original email to new email to bunch of stakeholders.

Finding difficulty to run the script.
Scenario, I get an email which has Company Name list. So whenever I am running this script it should replace with company name listed on the original email.

Below is my script.

```
Sub Test()

Dim origEmail As MailItem

Dim replyEmail As MailItem

Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

Dim strcompany As String

Dim strHTML As String


Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)

Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\test-.oft")

strcompany = InputBox("Issue : ", "Replace %company%")

strHTML = Replace(replyEmail.HTMLBody, "Company:", strissue)

replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody

replyEmail.Subject = replyEmail.Subject & origEmail.Reply.Subject


replyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show your code so far.

Comment: How are calling the template? Can you show your  code ?

Comment: Hi Om3r, 

I am using above script.

Comment: Hi Om3r, Any luck?

Comment: In the editor Tools | Options | Require Variable Declaration. For this existing module put Option Explicit at the top.

Comment: Can you add screen shot of the original email?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Explorer.SelectionChange` (use `Application.ActiveExplorer`) to track the selection change
2. Set up event handlers on the selected emails.
3. When `MailItem.Reply` event fires, you can read properties from the original message and populate the properties on the new message passed as the parameter to the event handler.
4. You can do the same for the messages replied to from the open inspectors (use `Inspectors.NewInspector` event to track the message opened in inspectors).

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

I am new to VBA. Could you please show when to add above changes in my code.

Comment: I cannot write the code, sorry. Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: above is my code where should i add above syntax to retrieve my result.

Sorry I am new to excel.